# Bash/Shell : CSV File Processing Issue

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

I have written a `bash` script that calls a Python script to scan for a vulnerability:

```
#scan.sh
while IFS=, read -r n d ;do
   python scan.py $d 443 | sed "s/^\(.\)/$n,\1/"
done < Input.csv
```

`Input.csv` looks like:

```
#Input.csv
1,abc.com
2,xyz.com
3,pqr.com
.........
```

`Output.csv` should look like:

```
1,abc.com,True,2016-03-06
1,abc.com,False,2016-03-06
1,abc.com,True,2016-03-06
1,abc.com,True,2016-03-06
2,xyz.com,False,2016-03-06
2,xyz.com,False,2016-03-06
2,xyz.com,False,2016-03-06
2,xyz.com,False,2016-03-06
3,pqr.com,True,2016-03-06
3,pqr.com,True,2016-03-06
3,pqr.com,True,2016-03-06
3,pqr.com,True,2016-03-06
........................
```

Each `ID` will have four entries in the `output.csv` with varying results.

1. If any of the four entries for an `ID` is `True`, it has to be `True` and need to have one entry for a `ID`.
2. If all four entries for an `ID` are `False`, it has to be `False` and with one entry.
3. If all four entries for an `ID` are `True`, it has to be `True` and with one entry.

Thus:

```
# processed_out.csv

1,abc.com,True,2016-03-06
2,xyz.com,False,2016-03-06
3,pqr.com,True,2016-03-06
........
```

How can I achieve this case only by using awk/sed?

FYI : I'm a beginner in bash scripting.

Comment: any reason you want to do this in bash? You've already got a python script doing the "Important" work. wouldn't it be easier to just have that script spit out the data in your desired format in the first place?

Comment: @MarcB I don't want alter any single line edit in the master script  and to be frank i'm more interested in learning something new in bash programming ;)

Comment: @MarcB Even in the #scan.sh script, I'm inserting/prefixing the ID of each domain ( sed "s/^\(.\)/$n,\1/" ) to the output result. I'm in love with bash actually !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward with awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    $3 == "True" {ntrue++} 
    NR%4 == 0 {
        $3 = (ntrue > 0) ? "True" : "False"
        print
        ntrue = 0
    }
' output.csv > processed_out.csv
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's clean method

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ pr -4ats, file | 
  awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=4) 
                        if($i=="True") {$3=$i; break}; 
                     print $1,$2,$3,$4}'

1,abc.com,True,2016-03-06
2,xyz.com,False,2016-03-06
3,pqr.com,True,2016-03-06
```

`pr` to bring the related records together, override status with any "True" value in the corresponding positions.

Comment: Nice. An alternative to `pr` is `paste -d, - - - - < file`